# Retrieve Json file data into datatable by onchange event

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to access a database using a on dropdown on-change function. Then, trying to store that data into one `.json` file. I want to retrieve that data into a DataTable without refreshing the current page.

**Issue**: I am not able to store json file's data into the DataTable. The worst part is I am not getting a single error while doing this. I am sure I am making some mistake.

here is the Sample data Which get stored into json file....

```
{"data":[{"ID":"1","ca_nm":"Candidate1 test","ma_nm":"Deep Bhatt"},{"ID":"2","ca_nm":"Candidate2 test","ma_nm":"Deep Bhatt"},{"ID":"3","ca_nm":"Candidate3 test","ma_nm":"Deep Bhatt"}]
```

Here is the code from which the data is stored into the json file.

```
   $vi_tab = $_POST['emp_teX'];
   if($vi_tab=='1'){
  $array_return = array();
        $query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,name,mana_name FROM sales ORDER BY id ASC");
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $pass_array['ID'] = $rows['id'];
            $pass_array['ca_nm'] = $rows['name'];
            $pass_array['ma_nm'] = $rows['mana_name'];
            array_push($array_return, $pass_array);
        }


        $changetab = fopen('tabdata.json', 'w');
        fwrite($changetab, '{"data":');
        fwrite($changetab, json_encode($array_return));
        fwrite($changetab, "}");
        fclose($changetab);
        }
```

This is the ajax that I function am using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function OnselectionChangge(table_te){

         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
            url: 'changeTeam2.php',
            data: 'emp_teX='+table_te,
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function(outdata){
                //alert(outdata);
                if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataxxx')) {
                $('#dataxxx').DataTable({

                    "ajax": 'tabdata.json',
                    "dataSrc": "data",
                    "bRetrieve": 'true',
                    "destroy": "true",
                    "searching": "false",
                    "aoColumns": [ {
                    "ID": "ID"
                    },
                     {
                     "ca_nm": "Candidate"
                     },
                    {
                    "ma_nm": "Manager"
                     }
                    ]
                });

            }
        }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Here is the code of the drop down,

```
     <select id="tea" name="tea" 
       onchange="OnselectionChangge(this.value)" required>
                    <option value="">Select One Team</option>
                    <option value="1">Team One</option>
                    <option value="2">Team two</option>
                    <option value="3">Team three</option>

                </select>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the file data?

Comment: "Even worst part is I am not getting a single error while doing this thing"  And where are you looking for errors?  Have you looked in your browser's Javascript console?  Have you looked at the response of the ajax call to tabdata.json (made by your DataTable constructor) in your Network tab?  Have you check to make sure you're actually going inside your `if (!$.fn.DataTable.....` check?

Comment: @musa I am returning the file data. I already gave the data sample which get store into that tabdata.json file.

Comment: where is the error output ?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes,Javascript is running,ajax function is working,data is getting store into that tabjson.json file every time I change drop down value. Just not able to retrieve it into datatable.

Comment: Okay, but you didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: @IvanBarayev I am not getting any error in this..